# Could not install NuGet package MPI.NET 1.3.0 in MS Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, visual-studio-2017, mpi, nuget-package

I am trying to install NuGet package MPI.NET 1.3.0 to MS Visual Studio 2017 C# project. I am getting the following error:

> Could not install package 'MPI.NET 1.3.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

I have tried to create C# projects in different versions of .NET Framework, but it would not install. On the official GitHub site for this package ([MPI.NET GitHub repository](https://github.com/jmp75/MPI.NET)) it is written that the package is updated for .NET 4.0. I have tried creating 4.0 and lower projects, but no success.

Help anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the packages available on nuget.org, [version 1.3.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MPI.NET/1.3.0) targets .NET 4.6.2, whereas [version 1.2.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MPI.NET/1.2.0) targets .NET 4.0. So if you try to install version 1.2.0 of the package into your project, you should be okay. It sounds like the GitHub documentation needs to be updated to reflect this new reality.

(Personally I would bump the major version number for a change like this, given that it's not necessarily backwardly compatible for existing users, but semantic versioning is less cut and dried than it sometimes sounds.)